# Trying to display data from other table in a single view using MVC5 and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do you display list of data from two different table in a single view in MVC5 EF?

For example, I have two tables(Project/Proposer) and in `Proposer` View I have `Create`, `Edit` and `Details` pages. When user clicks on a `Details` link the page displays the details for that proposer. But, how do I display list of project for that proposer?

This is my current `ProposerController`:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Proposer proposer = db.Proposers.Find(id);
    var proposers = db.Proposers.ToList();
    if (proposer == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(proposer);
}
```

Comment: You need to specify more details and provide some code samples.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. sorry about that. I have tried to attached some screenshots but, as I have just resisted with this site it's not allowing me to upload screenshots., Here is some screenshots in below link.  http://www.4shared.com/folder/RyXYJDU-/Code.html

Comment: It's your first question so I will try to help you. Please first read [article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about good questions. Then when you write the answer you have much more options than plain text. There is a help button for question textbox. You can also edit your existing question.

Comment: @HarshPanchal here read about `ViewModels`, because this question has been asked 1000s of times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc

Comment: Thanks for your comment but, i have tried using ViewModels but got confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ query should be something like:

```
var proposer = db.Proposers
    .Include(x => x.Projects)
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
```

The `Include` statement tells Entity Framework to include the Projects data with the same query, resulting in only a single call to the DB.

Then you access the Projects like:

```
foreach(var project in proposer.Projects)
{
    // Do your stuff
}
```

That said, I highly recommend you read up some more on ViewModels and best practices on how to pass and/or convert your data into the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `db` is your context, you can access your table `Project` with `db.Projects`, just like you did with `Proposer`. Then, just compose a ViewModel as suggested in the comments and display it - voilà.